# Footer from a web app is hidden inside a WKWebView

Tags: html, css, ios, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView that loads a web app that has a footer inside it. The problem I am facing is that the web app seems to be taller than the allocated space in my WkWebView. This results in the footer being hidden until I scroll all the way down.

Here is my web app code:

```
    const TestPage = () => (
  <Wrapper>
    <header>
      <Heading>Welcome to My React Page</Heading>
    </header>
    <main>
      <p>This is the main content of your page.</p>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <div>&copy; 2023 Your Company</div>
    </footer>
  </Wrapper>
);
```

And the CSS:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  header {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  main {
    padding: 20px;
    
  }
  footer {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
`;
```

As you can see in the images below, the footer is hidden unless I scroll to the bottom. What I would like is that the footer is always fixed at the bottom of the viewport.

[image]
[image]